# Pick-up's are welcome from the north side of our red nets

Tags: word-meaning

[**Source**](https://www.bigcherries.co.nz/cherries/)

> Pick-up's are welcome from the north side of our red nets.

This sentence is an advertisement of a cherry farm. What does the term "pick-up" mean? Is it referring to a truck or the person or the activities to pick up the cherry?

Comment: More context would be useful. What country? A link to the ad, perhaps?

Comment: I should think a truck will not be required to transport a single cherry!

Comment: It could mean "pick your own". The "red nets" might refer to protective netting.

Comment: We really need to know what the "red nets" are.

Comment: See added source above. "Pick up's" refers to customer visits to receive orders. "Red nets" are apparently used in cherry farming, as are blue ones. See [**this article**](http://www.stuff.co.nz/southland-times/news/5522/Blue-nets-appear-on-Central-orchard) for more.

Answer (score 3):

> Pick-up's are welcome from the north side of our red nets.

A [pick-up](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pickup) is when you go in person to the supplier (or send someone) and take away something that you have ordered. Delicious NZ cherries, in this case.

Here is a sign on the outside of an [electrical distribution business](http://delande.com/contact-us/location-directions/).

[image]

The apostrophe which pluralizes pick-up is what is known as a [green grocer's apostrophe](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/greengrocer's_apostrophe) and is considered wrong by prescriptivists.

The red nets would likely refer to nets placed over cherry trees to prevent birds and other creatures from harvesting their crop. It would be a visual reference point for the visitor to locate the point where the pick-up order would be made available. Photo from [here](http://www.smart-net-systems.com/agricultural-nets).

[image][image]

In this case, most of the nets are not red, so "red nets" directs the visitor to a specific part of the farm (satellite image of the particular NZ cherry farm in question from Google maps):

See the excellent link from @P.E.Dant (very funny user name) which indicates the color coding of the nets is significant in controlling the sunlight the cherry trees receive.

Answer (score 1):

Your sentence as it stands is ambiguous.

Usually in a retail situation

> pick-up(s)

refers to the area where one goes to collect the things that have been purchased, especially since they used the preposition "from"

[image]
<sub>(source: [ctvnews.ca](http://london.ctvnews.ca/polopoly_fs/1.2683446.1449078070!/httpImage/image.jpg_gen/derivatives/landscape_620/image.jpg))</sub>

However, it is possible that because of the enormous size difference between a pickup and a standard sized car

http://media.jrn.com/images/cheap_oil_changes_jpeg-09442_12649687_ver1.0_640_480.jpg

They may be referring to the vehicle, wanting trucks to be parked separately.

Comment: It couldn't be referring to the truck because of the "from".  Otherwise it should say "pick-ups are welcome (to park) at the north side of our red nets".  My guess is that in this case "pick-ups" means "cherries you pick yourself", although it still sounds strange to me.

Comment: @Andrew It would be strange, it is usually referred to as U-pick or pick-your-own (PYO), thus my question above "Where is the farm?"

Comment: Agreed.  Apparently the farm is in NZ (see the question for a link to the source) so I guess now I know what they call it over there.

Comment: Worth noting that the vehicles aren't called "pick-up trucks" in New Zealand, except perhaps rarely from the influence of American English. They're called "utes" (short for "utility").